# Can we use the DataTables plugin inside a custom Query plugin?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am trying to create custom plug-in in jQuery using DataTable jQuery plug-in to display list of record. I am using following code to display list of record in data table.
It is not display list of record and there is no error in console.

```
var jQueryScript = document.createElement('script');
    jQueryScript.setAttribute('src', '/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js');
    jQueryScript.setAttribute('src', '/Scripts/dataTables.responsive.min.js');
    
    document.head.appendChild(jQueryScript);
    
    (function ($) {
        $.fn.Grid = function (options) {
            options = $.extend({
                responsive: true,
                processing: true, 
                serverSide: true, 
                filter: true, 
                orderMulti: false,
                columns: [],
                order: [[1, "asc"]],
                url: "",
                type: "",
            }, options);
           
            $.fn.Grid.method = function (options) {
               var dataTable = $('#table1').DataTable({
                    "responsive": options.responsive,
                    "processing": options.processing, // for show progress bar
                    "serverSide": options.responsive, // for process server side
                    "filter": options.responsive, // this is for disable filter (search box)
                    "orderMulti": options.responsive, // for disable multiple column at once
                    "ajax": {
                        "url": options.url,
                        "type": options.type,
                        "datatype": "json"
                    },
                    select: true,
                    language: {
                        processing: "<img src='/images/loading.gif'/>",
                        emptyTable: "No records to display",
                        "paginate": {
                            "previous": "<<",
                            "next": ">>"
                        }
                    },
                    "order": options.order,
                    "columns": options.columns
                });
               return dataTable;
            };
            console.log('dataTable: ', $.fn.Grid.method(options));
            $.fn.Grid.settings = options;
            return this.each(function () {
                var $element = $(this);
                $element.html($.fn.Grid.method(options));
    
            });
        };
    }(jQuery));
```

many thanks in advance

Comment: There's been quite a bit of [discussion on this](https://www.google.com/search?q=use+one+jquery+plugin+inside+another+site:stackoverflow.com) already.

Comment: If your code can use datatables, then your plugin can use datatables.  Generally, as long as datatables is included first (like jquery is installed before datatables).  But depends on how it's written.  The link above (first hits or so) provide a way to *check* if it's there, but that's not needed to use it. The question is then, if you remove the "plugin" parts of your code, does it still work?  I would guess not from the line `$('#table1').DataTable` and `this.each` and .html(). But without an [mcve], there's no way to tell if it will work in your limited scenario (of only having one table)